# Tinyint(byte),SmallInt(Int16) not compatible with Enum in EF5

Tags: entity-framework-5, sqldatatypes

Using Database first design and having tinyint (or smallint) column:

```
[MyEnumColumn] [tinyint] NOT NULL
```

I mapped this column to Enum Type in EDM with

```
External Type: NSpace.MyEnumType
Name:MyEnumType
UnderlyingType:Byte
```

Where NSpace.MyEnumType is defined like this:

```
public enum MyEnumType 
{ One, Two, Three, All }
```

Only to get this error when trying to load entity from context:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> No corresponding object layer type could be found for the conceptual
>   type 'EntityDataModel.MyEnumType'.
>
> The following information may be useful in resolving the previous
>   error:
>
> The underlying type of CLR enumeration type does not match the
>   underlying type of EDM enumeration type.

Same applies if I use [Smallint] and [Int16] but once I change database to [Int] and enum type to [Int32] the error is gone.

Why do I need to store enum value in 4Byte (Int) data field instead of 1Byte (Tinyint) when enums in 99.9% time don't have more than 256 items or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Well if anyone is interested the problem is in enum's default type:

```
public enum MyEnumType 
{ One, Two, Three, All }
```

Since enum defaults to type **int**, [Underlying Type:{**Byte**}] doesn't match type of [External Type] {MyEnumType:Int} so to fix it for my original tinyint field you need to define your enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnumType : byte
{ One, Two, Three, All }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify both in the Model and in the Enumerator that you are using tinyInt and Byte .

in Enumerator definition 
 `public enum MyEnumType : byte
{ One, Two, Three, All }`

then in the Model class file

```
 [Column(TypeName = "tinyint")]
    public MyEnumType? MyEnum { get; set; }
```