# asp.net mvc - how to save a model with enum fields?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, repository-pattern

My model is defined as follows:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public enum LogType
    {
        Login = 0,
        Login_Fail = 1
    }

    [Table("UserLog")]
    public class UserLog
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Des { get; set; }
        public LogType Type { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Base type of **Type** field in the **UserLog** table is **tinyint**.

Login controller code as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult Login(UserViewModel model)
{
    if (userRepository.CheckUserLogin(model.UserName, model.Password))
    {
        UserLog log = new UserLog();
        log.Date = DateTime.Now;
        log.Des = "";
        log.Type = LogType.Login;

        userRepository.AddUserLog(model.UserName, log);
        userRepository.Save();

        Session["LoginUser"] = model.UserName;
     }
}
```

And Login Repository code as follows:

```
public void AddUserLog(string username, UserLog log)
{
     User user = GetUserByUserName(username);
     if (user != null)
         user.UserLogs.Add(log);
}
```

The problem is that information is properly stored in **UserLog** table, but the **Type** field remains **Null**!

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Linq-to-sql? Something else? What versions? Are you using Sql Server? MySQL? What does Add() do?  We can't see how your Repository operates... you didn't include that code.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of EF, Sounds like this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318782/tinyintbyte-smallintint16-not-compatible-with-enum-in-ef5  enum type is, by default of type int...

Comment: I am using EF, The problem was solved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this solution:

```
public int Type { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public LogType UserLogType
{
    get { return (LogType)Type; }
    set { Type = (int)value; }
}
```