# EF5 Code first enum from another assembly not being mapped

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 CodeFirst and I have a POCO entity which uses, as one of it's columns, an enum defined in another assembly. When i try to construct my data context I get the following error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  No corresponding object layer
>   type could be found for the conceptual type [EnumType]...

When I move the entity to the same assembly as the enum, everything works.

My question is, is it possible to configure this to work correctly? Other questions on this topic (e. g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456095/ef5-enum-mapping-to-external-type-issue)), seem to suggest an edmx-based approach for configuring external enums. How can I do this in code-first?

Comment: Hmm I had no problems in defining enums in separate assemblies in the past. I even double checked now and I can construct my context just fine.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud do you know of anything else that would produce this error with that solution?

Comment: Seems like this: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/532

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should work
install [EF powertools if you havent already](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Then right click on the context and try Generate read only diagram.
Check the Output window for any issues